# Angular 2 how to use nested components

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

I have just started using Angular 2 and I run into a problem when using components. I want to use "NavigationComponent" component inside template of my "MyApp" component.

This is "MyApp" component(/app/app.component.ts) :

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/router';
import {NavigationComponent} from './navigation/navigation.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class MyApp {
}
```

/app/app.component.html:

```
<nav class="pink accent-3" role="navigation">
    <na-navigation>Loading...</na-navigation> // <-- this is my not working attempt :(
</nav>
<footer class="page-footer">
    <!--footer-->
</footer>
```

/app/navigation/navigation.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from 'angular2/core';
import { MenuItem } from './menuItem';

@Component({
  selector: 'na-navigation',
  templateUrl: 'app/navigation/navigation.component.html'
})
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {

  menuItems: MenuItem[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
      this.menuItems.push(new MenuItem("Sign in", "signIn"));
      this.menuItems.push(new MenuItem("Create account", "createAccount"));
  }
}
```

/app/navigation/navigation.component.html:

```
<div class="nav-wrapper container">
    <a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li *ngFor="#menuItem of menuItems">
            <a>{{menuItem.label}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

But in the end my tag is not rendered, instead of menu list, there is only "Loading...".

How should I pass "NavigationComponent" into "MyApp" to have in available in "app.component.html" template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to list all components and directives you use in the template in the `directives: []` array.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: [NavigationComponent],
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class MyApp {
}
```

If the code of the components is in the same file, ensure that you don't refer to classes that are further down in your file because then they are unknown when you use them. Classes in TypeScript are not hoisted.

You're on the safe side if you have one file per class.